# Can't connect to MySQL server from Visual Studio(C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl

So, I want to connect to mySQL server (ubuntu, virtualbox) with ssl certificate. I've already created user for ssl connection and copied it from my virtualbox, tested connection through xampp `mysql -ukek -p -h 192.168.254.128 --ssl-cert "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\client-cert.cer" --ssl-key "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\client-cert.cer"`. Everything works perfect.
Now I want to make a simple which connects to mysql server. I also created .pfx file `openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem -certfile ca-cert.pem -out client.pfx` and copied it to my desktop. Then I've installed mysql connector, added to to using. But when I try to connect with this connection string:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(
                "datasource=192.168.254.128;user=kek; password=1;" +
                "CertificateFile=C:\\Users\\Sergey\\Desktop\\client.pfx" +
                "CertificatePassword=1;" +
                "SSL Mode=Required"))
```

I get an exception : `"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException" in MySql.Data.dll. File not found.`

UPD: i missed semicolon. I've noticed that if I remove "CertificateFile=C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\client.pfx;" and "CertificatePassword=1;" it connects to my server anyway. Does it works right? Because if I don't use `ssl-key` and `ssl-cert` in xampp I can't connect.

Comment: Maybe the mysql server has no access to your user desktop folder... what have you tried so far?

Comment: semicolon ; missing at the end of the second line in connection string

Comment: it was semicolon... thanks a lot!